# Can you create output for SQL subsets problem

Tags: mysql, sql, subset

SQL gurus please help with a SQL problem:
I have a table of parts, group discounts, orders.

[image]

Looking for output / view

| Part | disc | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC. | grp1 | 2 |
| ABC. |  | 1 |
| BCD. |  | 2 |
| CDE. | grp1 | 2 |
| CDE. |  | 2 |
| EFG. | grp1 | 2 |
| HIJ. | grp2 | 3 |
| HIJ. |  | 2 |
| JKL. | grp2 | 3 |

Can you help derive a view (preferably) or procedure to give this output.

Any pointers on a suitable approach greatly appreciated.

Comment: i can obviously find whether orders contain completed sets.. that's not a problem

Comment: How are you deciding the quantity that each group gets? For example, why is ABC split into 2 for grp1 and 1 for NULL group (instead of 1 and 2).

Comment: Well  my failed approach has been a view on order to give count of indiviual items for a discountgroup. e.g. a part can only belong to one discount group  vs view of discountgroup to give how many items in each discountgroup. matching on counts gives me the fact that the part on order qualifies for a discount. But where i'm stuc k on is taking this further to derive how many times this set divides into the order, and the associated remainders that don't qualify for discount

Comment: Stidgeon, ABC qty1 + CDE qty1 + EFG qty1 = one matching set. i.e qty of 1 plus we have an extra set of ABC qty1 + CDE qty1 + EFG qty 1 = another matching set. but we have total of 3 ABC on order so one of the ABC items doesn't qualify for discount.

Comment: corrected CDE output. was in error

Comment: OK i figured it out....   create view v_cart2P_c AS
select tokenx,group, count(*) as setcount,  min(qtyx) as minqtyx from v_order  group by tokenx,bundleset... basicaly the min(qty) represents the number of times the sets match when the count(*) matches the same count as the group number of entries